# How to create a reference table in MS Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2013

I would like to create a reference table in Excel like this:

[image]

So everywhere in my workbook or worksheet I type X111, Excel shows the value of 2400.

How could I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a second sheet and use `VLOOKUP` to do this.

For example, to get the value alone you can use the formula:

```
=VLOOKUP("X111", Sheetname!A1:B16, 2)
```

If you're performing a calculation somewhere, insert this formula as needed.

This isn't as concise or "clean" as specifying variables as you might using VBScript, but hopefully this works for you.

Comment: For that to work, I think you need to make sure that column A is sorted.