# How can I create a table with values in all columns that change relative to one another?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, conditional-formatting, cell-format

I want to create a table in Excel where all the resulting values in the other columns change relative to the raw value I modify. Think of it like a multi-way conversion table, where you get to change either value to see how it affects the rest of the columns

Example:

```
      A       B         C       D
1  Item  | Price | Quantity | Total Cost
   ======|=======|==========|===========
2  Bread |  $2   |     2    | =PRODUCT(B2;C2)
3  Milk  |  $3   |     2    | $6
4  Eggs  |  $2   |     5    | $10
```

If I change either the Quantity or the Price of Bread, then the Total Cost would automatically change as well. That's easy to achieve with the product formula `=PRODUCT(B2;C2)` in cell `D2`. The challenge I am trying to overcome is, if I want to modify Total Cost or `D2` (by typing in a value), then Price must change relative to `=D2/C2`.

I believe this can be achieved with a combination of "Formatting Conditions" (or "Format Cell") and Formulas in hidden columns, but I don't know how I would enter a raw typed value in the same cell as a formula.

Maybe [VLOOKUP](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vlookup-function-0bbc8083-26fe-4963-8ab8-93a18ad188a1), [from this question](https://superuser.com/questions/907807/how-to-create-a-reference-table-in-ms-excel) can be helpful as well, to hide some of the backend values.

Another example:
[image: Stats of Ships]
In this example, I can change Count and the rest of the values will change accordingly. I want the ability to change any value and have other columns follow suit.

Comment: In the other example you provided, pick one of the cells where the value changes after you change Count. If you change that other value, does Count update? Without VBA replacing the formulas you overwrote with constants, I would expect not.

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible from a formula perspective, this can only be accomplished by used VBA.

Deep at the very center of the spreadsheet model is the notion that a cell contains either a formula or a constant that defines its own value.  A formula cannot place content into another cell (array spilling being the only exception).

Comment: The value in the cell itself does not necessarily need to be shown. It can be masked by the formatting rules. I'm currently playing with Conditional Formatting, but my challenge is formatting a specific cell based on the conditions of a different cell. For instance, if I enter text into a specific cell, the formatting conditions evaluate as True (for the other blank cells). So, if the cell is blank, it will show a certain formatting based on another cell that is hidden. Now I need a way to show the product of that hidden cell and the entered text. I'm so close to finding a solution/workaround.

Comment: If I don't find an easy way to do this, then I'll look into creating a VBA script, as you suggested. I think I will need to find out how to replace constants with formulas if I manually update another cell. Basically, it will have to check for the last manually update cell within the column, and then replace other cells in the same row with formulas based on a rule for each column.